# Sql ORDER BY using group of fields

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by

Is it possible to use `ORDER BY (EMPRESA) DESC,CD_PROC DESC, (EMPRESA,CD_DIRECAO,DT_INI_DIRECAO) DESC`

Lets say , can i `order by` a `group by`. Can i set alias to `group by`?

Comment: It be better to post example data and what you would like to see out of the query. It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi Leonel. I would suggest possibly rewording your question, just so some folks better understand. 

Additionally, try pasting an example of your code so we can see what you're working with. Then, we can better help you :)

Comment: this is far complex....sorry, but thanks for hel anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You have to specify each key individually:

```
ORDER BY EMPRESA DESC, CD_PROD DESC, CD_DIRECAO DESC, DT_INI_DIRECAO DESC
```